# Are there any built-in keys I can use in my segmentation rules in Intuit's Wasabi?

Tags: ab-testing, intuit-wasabi

I am trying to use user segmentation rules in Wasabi. Are there any built-in keys that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can segment on these three things:

- The passed segmentation profile
- The HTTP Header values
- The context parameter

For example, if you wanted to segment on the context, you would build a segmentation rule `context = QA`, for getting users of chrome a (naive) approach would be to use a segmentation rule that matches the regular expression `".*chrome.*"`. So for example `User-Agent =~ ".*curl.*" & context = "QA"` would match users who are in the context QA (`?context=QA`) and use `curl`.

Note that sadly the alphabetical operators (e.g. contains) which you can select in the UI are currently broken, we are working on a fix for the (still precompiled) library Hyrule which leverages those rules. For now I recommend converting your rules to the text view or test them to see if they work or not. There is also a validation in place when you try to save a rule.